# transformation of date format extracted from a .csv file

Tags: c#, csv, date, datetime

I am in the process of extracting the data from some .csv files, in line number 5 of the file comes the following data: Date: 21 / December / 2017
This data is used to add a new column to the file with the date of the current day, by which to verify that if it is the correct file it is necessary for the program to understand the date and transform it to the established base format of data.
I specify the transformation that I need

Date: 21 / December / 2017 -----> 2017-12-21

The steps to follow would be the following;

1. Take row number 5 of the .csv file

2.Read the date and the transformation to the format previously shown "Date: 21 / December / 2017" -----> "2017-12-21"

I do not know if the way he raised this correct

I have already tried several things, such as:
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact ("21 / December / 2017", "dd / MM / yyyyy", Null);

But in this case it does not understand "December"  I would really appreciate it if anyone could guide me in this problem.

development in c #

visual code.

Comment: There are a number of tools which make reading CSVs very simple and will do this sort of thing for you (once you give them the proper format).

Comment: could you comment on some of these tools?@https://stackoverflow.com/users/1070452/plutonix

Answer (score 0):

use `"dd / MMMM / yyyy"` as your format instead.
`"MMMM"` means it will take the full name of the month.
Also, `yyyy` would be enough for a four-digit year. It seems you typed an extra `y`.

See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) for more info.